# SQL multijoin with null values

Tags: sql, join, null

I have the following tables:

```
 T         T  A  B          T  A  C
---      -----------      -----------
 1         1  x  y          2  x  z
 2        
 3
```

And now i would like to join them and get the following one:

```
T    A    B    C
------------------
1    x    y   null
2    x   null  z
3   null null null
```

Is that possible in SQL?

Thanks alot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LEFT OUTER JOINS`, using your first table as the left table. The coalesce is there to resolve / best effort on your assumed duplicated column A (value 'x').

```
SELECT t.T, COALESCE(tab.A, tac.a) as A, tab.B, tac.C
FROM T t
LEFT OUTER JOIN SecondTable tab
ON tab.T = t.T
LEFT OUTER JOIN ThirdTable tac
ON tac.T = t.T;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a more generic way? i actually do not know which columns are duplicated or how many tables i have.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Depending on your RDBMS, you could drop down to dynamic sql, determine the columns of the tables, probably do a rudimentary type safety check, and then collate distinct and coalesce common columns, but this would all be rather messy.